# exceptions in unix .forward mail forwarding

Tags: linux, email, unix, forwarding

I'm currently having IMAP-based email (over which I have no control):

myusername@academia.edu

forwarded to an external address using an entry in the .forward file:

\myusername, my_otheremail@gmail.com

I've setup the gmail account also to send from this .edu email account, but for reference I bcc myusername@academia.edu in the email I send from gmail.

Just out of curiousity, is there a way to define a rule with .forward (or something similar) such as:

"if the incoming email is from my_otheremail@gmail.com, don't forward it to my_otheremail@gmail.com"?

Obviously this *isn't* something that's handled at the mail client level - it's too late by then. I also concede I could just get gmail to handle this with the above rule (if the email I'm sending is from myusername@academia.edu, trash it), but this loses me flexibility if I want to email something out to my gmail account.

I hope that isn't too compilcated - I essentially want to have my cake and eat it. If someone can think of a better implementation, please do suggest. I kind of like the ability to have access to both email systems, so ditching one isn't really an option.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It may be overkill, but this is what I use [`procmail`](http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/) for.